# Substract a given percentage amount to a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am getting different values from an API and I need to perform a math operation with that data.

I have the main value, for example:

```
37.8 (it's a Number)
```

and the percentage:

```
0.01% (a String)
```

What I need to do is:

```
37.8 -0.01%
```

But the percentage could be positive as well. How can I do that? I can use jQuery as well.

My expected result is the difference between the main Number and the percentage, wether is added or substracted.

Comment: The only relevant "problem" is parsing the string as a number -> `parseFloat()`. The other "problem" is just math and not the scope of SO.

Comment: Just to be clear, `"0.01%"` **really** means "zero point zero one percent"? That is, a tenth of a penny if you apply it to a dollar or pound? *"What I need to do is: 37.8 -0.01%"* What should the result be?

Comment: Yes but could be 1% or 3% or -5%

Comment: @Sergi  please add your code effort too. Also your expected result

Comment: You could try `$.magic(number, percent)`

Comment: @Sergi - Again, what should the result of `37.8 -0.01%` be?

Comment: i upvoted your question because of all downvotes. i get what you want but i agree you could be more specific with what your expected outcome should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you do is turn the percentage string into a number:

```
const percent = percentString.replace("%", "") / 100;
```

That removes the `%` and converts to number, then divides by 100 because that's how you go from "percent" to a number you can use to apply that percent ("percent" meaning, literally, "per hundred").

Then you subtract the result of mulitplying the original number by that percent number to the original number:

```js
const number = 37.8;
const percentString = "0.01%";
const percent = percentString.replace("%", "") / 100;
const result = number - number * percent;
console.log(result);
```

Also works if the string is negative (and so you end up increasing the number):

```js
const number = 37.8;
const percentString = "-0.01%";
const percent = percentString.replace("%", "") / 100;
const result = number - number * percent;
console.log(result);
```

Examples using a more obvious calculation (100 and 10%):

```js
function example(percentString) {
    const number = 100;
    const percent = percentString.replace("%", "") / 100;
    const result = number - number * percent;
    console.log(number, "-", percentString, "=", result);
}
example("10%");
example("-10%");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 37.8           //number
var b = "0.01%"        //string
var c = parseFloat(b)  //converts to float, c = 0.01
var result = a-c*a/100
```

You get the values from API in the variables a and b. As you've mentioned, a is a number and b is a string. parseFloat converts b to a float value, which happens to be 0.01 in this case and assigns this to c. If your string value has a negative sign, parseFloat returns a negative value. So, there is no need to worry about the sign. Now when you subtract a*c/100 (i.e c% of a) from a, you get your result.

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is to parse the string, i assume it does not contain the actual percentage sign.

The next problem is the math as people have said.

For example :

5% = 37.8 * 1.05

-5% = 37.8 * 0.95

```js
const pct = parseFloat("0.01");
const result = 37.8 * ((100 + pct) / 100);
console.log(result);
```